# AngularJS wait for resource inside .run to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I have frontend built using AngularJs and a backend built using SailsJs.
I want to check before anything inside a controller is executed, whether or not the user is logged in. For that I am using a resource that makes a call. The problem is that Angular continues to execute before the resource returns anything.
So, I end up getting errors because of this incapacity of waiting for the resource to finish.

Is there any way to delay Angular's execution or some better method to check if the user is logged before you get to the controller?

Comment: I have not heard of anyone doing this from scratch, but Angular UI Router provides an awesome `resolve` facility that waits promises to be resolved before the controller is invoked on the view. Details [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mike suggestion a possible solution:

```
$stateProvider.state('inbox', {
    url: "/inbox",
    templateUrl: "js/components/inbox/index.html",
    controller: 'InboxCtrl',
    resolve: {
        Auth: 'Auth',
        auth: function(Auth){

            // Auth.fetch() is completed before continuing. 
            return Auth.fetch().$promise;
        }
    },
});
```